# Show different number of posts on second page of category

Tags: pages, pagination

On the first page of a specific category, I want WordPress to show 4 posts per page. On the following pages, however, I'd like to have 6 posts per page. I tried using a conditional query (see below), but this completely screwed up the number of posts per page...

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;                 
if ($paged == 1) {                              
    query_posts("posts_per_page=4&category_name=Neuigkeiten&paged=$paged");
}
elseif ($paged > 1) {
    query_posts("posts_per_page=6&category_name=Neuigkeiten&paged=$paged");
}
```

This leads to 3 posts being displayed in a wrong order. There's probably a stupid mistake in there, but I can't figure it out. Echoing the `$paged` variable works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is use [WordPress › Custom Post Limits « WordPress Plugins.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-limits/) That plugin gives options for  individual categories, first page and pages, archives and search results without needing custom loops in template files.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could solve my problem. However, I'd prefer a way to do this without a plugin...

Comment: oh what the hell, the plugin works like a charm. Thanks! :)

Comment: It does work well; it might be mu-plugins aware so that end users don't disable it, if that's a concern: http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:

http://wpdevelopertips.com/different-number-of-posts-in-pagination-pages/

It will show the code to show different number of posts in the second pagination pages onwards.

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.